# SSRS - "As the user viewing the report" error

Tags: sql-server, iis, reporting-services, kerberos

Trying to get "As the user viewer the report" working as the log in method for a data source in SSRS. When I try testing the connection, I'm getting this error: "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'."

Using Kerberos Configuration manager, I can verify that I have the proper SPNs in place and the account I'm running the SSRS Service with has proper delegation. I'm able to connect to the SQL server that is feeding the data source and verify the connection is using Kerberos. I'm also able to connect to a SQL Server instance on the reporting machine from my machine in SSMS and then access the data source's SQL Server through a linked server object with "Be made using the login's current security context" as the security type on the linked server. It appears that double hop is working properly when it is SQL Server instance to SQL Server instance, but not from Reporting Services to SQL Server. I've added  to the RSReportServer.config file. I've tried setting impersonate identity in the web.config file both to true and false. I'm guessing there is a problem with IIS's configuration somewhere, but I can't find what it is and haven't found anything else on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Basically "NTAUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" is a built-in IIS account that is present on your report server. In general, reports are being executed from this account that serves up the page to the user.

There were a few things that you to have setup:

- The application pool must be using an AD account which must have access to the DB.
- Your DS has to be set up with the following information:

  1. The Credentials securely stored in the report server must be selected.
  2. Windows credentials should be used while connecting to the data
     source must be checked.
  3. The authenticated user must be impersonated after a connection has been made to the
     data source must also be checked.

If you have both of these items setup, your report will use kerberos and it will impersonate your logged on user.

Note:  SQL must be setup for kerberos authentication.  In addition to it, your service account must be setup correctly in AD as well.

Comment: Hey, samwu! Thanks! Where do I go to set those DS settings? I'm not seeing them on the property page on the SSRS website.

Comment: you can refer to this link: [Configure stored credentials for a report-specific data source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/store-credentials-in-a-reporting-services-data-source?view=sql-server-ver15#bkmk_stored_credentials_data_source_native)